# add / subtract fixed percent to vector numbers

Tags: r

I am looking to randomly add or subtract a fixed percent to each number in a vector:

```
nums <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
```

In this case I wish to randomly adjust the 1's randomly by 0.05%. 
It means any given 1 may randomly then be 1.05 or .95.

I am trying to do this:

```
> 1 + (1*0.05)
[1] 1.05
> 1 + (1*-0.05)
[1] 0.95

# Code to sample the 0.05 or -0.05
    nums <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
    perc <- c(0.05,-0.05)
    new <- nums + (nums*sample(perc,1))
```

The desired output should be:

`(1.05,1.05,.95,.95,1.05)`

however im getting:

```
> new
[1] 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95
```

I see the error.. its actually applying the percent change to ALL in the vector versus 1x number individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
noise_adjust <- function(x){
  x + ((x)*sample(perc,1))
}
sapply(nums,noise_adjust)

> sapply(nums,noise_adjust)
 [1] 0.95 1.05 0.95 0.95 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 0.95 0.95 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95
```